# How To Create Folder in Local Storage/External Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
   import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
   import 'dart:io';
   void createAppFolder() async {
       final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
       final dirPath = '${directory.path}/some_name' ;
       await new Directory(dirPath).create();
    }
```

this whats I tried of course I set up the permission for writing to storage but this code creates a directory on this path  `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.test_app/files/some_name`
and whats I need is to be created on this path `/storage/emulated/0/some_name` any idea of whats im doing wrong or they are another way to do thats ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you want to create dir in `/storage/emulated/0` try this.

```
import 'dart:io';
 _createFolder()async{
final folderName="some_name";
final path= Directory("storage/emulated/0/$folderName");
if ((await path.exists())){
  // TODO:
  print("exist");
}else{
  // TODO:
  print("not exist");
  path.create();
}
```

}

Comment: this won't work unless the app has storage permission. Refer this answer which also includes permission request https://stackoverflow.com/a/64075888/13241651

Comment: im getting creation failed response when tried to create a folder

Answer (score 18):

**FOR ME THIS WORKS**
[permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

But first set the permissions right in your Android Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

THIS IS BY FAR THE BEST SOLUTION:
for both IOS and Android (BEST)

```
  Future<String> createFolder(String cow) async {
 final dir = Directory((Platform.isAndroid
            ? await getExternalStorageDirectory() //FOR ANDROID
            : await getApplicationSupportDirectory() //FOR IOS
        )!
        .path + '/$cow');
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
    if ((await dir.exists())) {
      return dir.path;
    } else {
      dir.create();
      return dir.path;
    }
  }
```

**NOTE**: 
If you name your `createFolder(".folder")` that folder will be hidden. 
If you create a `.nomedia` file in your folder, other apps won't be able to scan your folder.

**NOTE II**:
 As of Android 11 and above, apps have been banned from creating custom folders using "storage/emulated/0/$folderName"

The solution below is OBSOLETE as of Android 11 and above:
[Reference](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#app-specific-external)

```
Future<String> createFolder(String cow) async {
  final folderName = cow;
  final path = Directory("storage/emulated/0/$folderName");
  var status = await Permission.storage.status;
  if (!status.isGranted) {
    await Permission.storage.request();
  }
  if ((await path.exists())) {
    return path.path;
  } else {
    path.create();
    return path.path;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not able to see created "$folderName" folder in phone when I connected to computer.

Comment: Yes, connected phone to computer via usb cable. Please suggest.

Comment: @Kamlesh the folder is created in `Android>data>com.yourpackagename>files>your folder name`.

Comment: Not working I used same code but still directory is not showing in phone

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede ```getExternalStorageDirectory()```  creates in ``` Android>data>com.yourpackagename>files>your folder name```

Comment: @RayZion yes I checked the same but  it not shows any folder inside the files

Comment: Could you paste your code somewhere, let me look at it @ShubhamNarkhede

Answer (score 1):

As per the plugin code, `getExternalStorageDirectory()` function takes optional parameter of StorageDirectory type. You can try providing the type argument.
Available types are:

```
enum StorageDirectory {
  /// Contains audio files that should be treated as music.
  ///
  /// See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_MUSIC.
  music,

  /// Contains audio files that should be treated as podcasts.
  ///
  /// See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_PODCASTS.
  podcasts,

  /// Contains audio files that should be treated as ringtones.
  ///
  /// See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_RINGTONES.
  ringtones,

  /// Contains audio files that should be treated as alarm sounds.
  ///
  /// See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_ALARMS.
  alarms,

  /// Contains audio files that should be treated as notification sounds.
  ///
  /// See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS.
  notifications,

  /// Contains images. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_PICTURES.
  pictures,

  /// Contains movies. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_MOVIES.
  movies,

  /// Contains files of any type that have been downloaded by the user.
  ///
  /// See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS.
  downloads,

  /// Used to hold both pictures and videos when the device filesystem is
  /// treated like a camera's.
  ///
  /// See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DCIM.
  dcim,

  /// Holds user-created documents. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS.
  documents,
}
```

For additional details you can refer to [this code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/path_provider/lib/path_provider.dart)
If your issue still not solved you can raise a request to plugin author.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for thats but all of them not provide the path I need I test it i will see on the repo of the plugin if they are solution