# Flutter: Create app's custom local directory in iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio

I'm trying to implement a feature where my app creates a local directory to save some data. What I'm trying to achieve is to create a `complex/nested` local directory structure as Whatsapp did. On the Android platform, I'm able to get it done by referring to
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093733/how-to-create-folder-in-local-storage-external-flutter/64075888#64075888.)

The above post uses the path-provider `package` to create the desired directory using my app name. But, how to implement the same feature on the `iOS` platform, especially on the `permissions handling`, and does the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package able to handle this one?

Thank you