# How to create folder which user able to see in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, directory

I tried to create folder with path_provider package with this code.

```
final Directory directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      print("path1="+directory.path );// this is using path_provider
      String directoryPath = directory.path + '/bozzetto_camera';
      await Directory(directoryPath).create(recursive: true).then((value){
        print("path="+value.toString());
      });
```

And in console it shows **path=Directory: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.water_delivery_app/files/bozzetto_camera'**.
In file manager I could not find any folder.[I tried this answer but it did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093733/how-to-create-folder-in-local-storage-external-flutter)  I am using a real android device via usb. So how can create directory that user can see?

Comment: As of Android API 30+ you cannot create folders outside the scope of your application instead you've to use your apps' application `directory` which of course won't be visible in file manager. Follow this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40498) for more info and about [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)