# Error when downloading file from Flutter Amplify Storage

Tags: ios, flutter, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I get the error below when downloading an audio file from Amplify Storage on an iOS device, both Simulator and a device. It all works perfectly fine when doing it on an Android emulator and device.

When downloading a JSON-file from the Storage it's working on both platforms without errors.

The JSON I'm downloading in the app as a guest, while the audio file is downloaded as private, but I don't see why this should make a difference when it's working on Android.

```
StorageException(message: Unexpected error occurred with message: Domain: [NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: [4
LocalizedDescription: [The file doesn’t exist.
LocalizedFailureReason: [The file doesn’t exist.
LocalizedRecoverySuggestion: [, recoverySuggestion: This should not happen. There is a possibility that there is a bug if this error persists. Please take a look at https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/issues to see if there are any existing issues that match your scenario, and file an issue with the details of the bug if there isn't.
Issue encountered at: file: /Users/x/Documents/Github/TransscriberAI-App/Flutter/transscriber/ios/Pods/Amplify/Amplify/Categories/Storage/Error/StorageError.swift
function: recoverySuggestion line: 63, underlyingException: null)
```

Here is the code I use to download the file:

```dart
Future<String> getAudioPath(String key) async {
  final docDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final filePath = docDir.path + '/audio/$key';
  File file = File(filePath);
  final S3DownloadFileOptions options = S3DownloadFileOptions(
    accessLevel: StorageAccessLevel.private,
  );

  if (await file.exists()) {
    return filePath;
  } else {
    try {
      await Amplify.Storage.downloadFile(
        key: key,
        local: file,
        options: options,
      );
      return filePath;
    } on StorageException catch (e) {
      print('Error downloading file: $e');
      return 'null';
    }
  }
}
```

Update:
I have now created an issue on the Amplify flutter Github

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/1276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the /audio/ folder not existing on iOS. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59566775/17145317) tells how you can create the path, if it doesn't exist.