# Creating an app folder on an ios simulator in flutter does not work

Tags: flutter

I would like to create an app folder to store app related data into and the folder should be located "On my iPhone".

Ive tried the following code:

```
Future<String> createFolder(String cow) async {
 final dir = Directory((Platform.isAndroid
            ? await path_provider.getExternalStorageDirectory() //FOR ANDROID
            : await path_provider.getApplicationSupportDirectory() //FOR IOS
        )!
        .path + '/$cow');
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
    if ((await dir.exists())) {
      return dir.path;
    } else {
      dir.create();
      return dir.path;
    }
  }
```

When i open "Files" on an ios Simulator from the homescreen there is no folder created,
iam not sure which location is represented by "getApplicationSupportDirectory".

I found this code on this articel [How To Create Folder in Local Storage/External Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093733/how-to-create-folder-in-local-storage-external-flutter)

What iam doing wrong?
thank you

Comment: Isn't it  String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path; you have to use ?

Comment: https://medium.com/@mibcoder/folder-creation-in-flutter-a554c238b7e8

Answer (score 0):

instead of getApplicationSupportDirectory() use getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() for IOS