# how can i use path_provider to download files from bytes in external storage, in ios and android?

Tags: flutter, dart, path-provider

How can I use path_provider to download files from bytes in external storage, like download folder, like you try to make it get the application directory, writing it and moving to external storage, but it doesn't give me error and it don't make the download.

This is how I done the download to application storage:

```dart
var tempDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
var tempPath = tempDir.path;
var tempFile = File('$tempPath/${solicitacao.id}.pdf');
tempFile.writeAsBytesSync(solicitacao.matriculapdf);
if (selectedPdfs.any((file) => file.path == tempFile.path)) {
  selectedPdfs.remove(tempFile);
} else {
  selectedPdfs.add(tempFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

User [Permission Handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package for permission.

first set the permissions right in your Android Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This will work in both Android and IOS.

```
 Future<String> createFolder(String download) async {
    final dir = Directory((Platform.isAndroid
        ? await getExternalStorageDirectory() //FOR ANDROID
        : await getApplicationSupportDirectory() //FOR IOS
    )!
    .path + '/$download');
var status = await Permission.storage.status;
if (!status.isGranted) {
  await Permission.storage.request();
}
if ((await dir.exists())) {
  return dir.path;
} else {
  dir.create();
  return dir.path;
}}
```

Now save file into this folder

```
var tempPath =await createFolder(download);
var tempFile = File('$tempPath/${solicitacao.id}.pdf');
tempFile.writeAsBytesSync(solicitacao.matriculapdf);
  if (selectedPdfs.any((file) => file.path == tempFile.path)) {
     selectedPdfs.remove(tempFile);
   } else {
     selectedPdfs.add(tempFile);
   }
```

[Answer Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64075888/19807154)

Comment: for the (String download) i should name the name of the foulder? Like i'm running in my phone, the download path is named "Downloads".

Comment: Yes you have to assign name as per your requirement like "**Download**" .